# Python does not reads a fetched line from text file as in Dictionary format

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file-handling

I've a text input file with different inputs as below stored in dictionary and list format respectively. A portion of the text file is below:

```
#Drive-Size-Mapping
{'root' : 50 , '\usr' : 20, 'swap' : 1}
#OS-Version
[7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6]
```

As you can see the first line is in Dictionary format and the 2nd line is in List format.
Now, when I'm reading and storing the lines in variables, Python fails to recognize the format. This is my code I'm trying:

```
 f=open("C:\\Users\xyz\\Desktop\\Inputs.txt")
lines=f.readlines()
i = lines.index("#Drive-Size-Mapping\n")
di=dict()
di = lines[i+1]
print(di[0])
j = lines.index("#OS-Version\n")
list = lines[j+1]
print(list[0])
```

The out of above code is:

{
 {

i.e it just prints the item which is present in the first array index of the array.
What I want python to interpret these variables as dictionary and List respectively. So , if I do `print di["root"]`

My code should recognize it as dictionary and  print as `50`. And 
`print(list[0])` should recognize it as list and output `7.1.`

Please let me know how should the file lines be manipulated so as to make python interpret them in the format they are actually present?

Thank You

Comment: `di = lines[i+1]` just completely overwrites `di = dict()`. `index` only ever returns the first instance it meets, so that's not suited to repeated data either.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the above answers:

Use:

```
 ast.literal_eval()
```

But remove/replace "\" from the keys of the dictionary as it can create unicode error in literal_eval() function

One more error in the code, after converting to dictionary, you cannot do d[0] as dictionaries are not indexed

Comment: Good point(s)! The escape character is not going to go down too well.

Comment: Yes right. I used d[0] just for showing what is python interpreting right now. After using literal_eval(lines[j+1]) it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The function `readlines` does what it says: it *reads lines*. You and I can recognize that the two lines are a Python dict and a Python list, but Python cannot and also should not.

It seems to me that you are reading configuration settings in from a file with Python source in it. A more standard way to do that is to use an `.ini` file. Look at the module `configparser`.

Comment: An `.ini` file? What am I missing here?

Comment: OP says, I want Python to interpret these variables as dictionary and list respectively. So the Python literals in the input file are to be interpreted as data. OP could use `ast.literal_eval()` for that, but I think that's the wrong approach.

Comment: Although my query is done is with above answer literal_eval , but I'd like to know about configparser as well. Seems something to hit with python core library and making some manipulations in the data structure.

Comment: Storing structured data as Python literals in text files may seem an obvious way to go, but it is a dead end. Config files have more forgiving syntax, and `configparser` will give you a decent error message if you get the syntax wrong, and even then will do its best to interpret the parts it *can* understand. `ast.literal_eval` will just say `SyntaxError` and leave you (or worse still, your user) in the dark about what is wrong. If you must persist Python data structures to disk (and there are sometimes very good reasons to do that), use `pickle`, not snippets of Python code stored as strings.

Answer (score 1):

The lines you are getting from the file are `string`. If you want to convert them to `dict` or `list` objects, you can use `literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

...
d = literal_eval(lines[i+1])
...
l = literal_eval(lines[i+1])
```

If you can change the format of the input file, I would look into modifying it to a `json` file to store and load your objects conveniently with the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html).